# Getting info of file packaged / included in jar resources running in servlet container

Tags: java, servlets

From java servlet 3.0 Spec it is possible to have any static resource files in **WEB-INF/lib/*.jar** and in the *.jar alone to have: **META-INF/resources** directory / folder and in browser it is possible to request the resources on the "context path":
E.g.: I have: **apptest/WEB-INF/lib/test1.jar**

In the test1.jar I have:
**META-INF/resources/js/script1.js**
then I can request in browser:

http://srv/apptest/js/script1.js

Is there possibility in the servlet / filter / ... using "virtual path":

"js/script1.js"

to get the "modified date" and "modification time" and other info of the static file "script1.js" ?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The closest possible I can get is to use:

Somewhere I have `pagctx` as `javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext`, then:

```
String virtualPath = "js/script1.js";
ServletContext svltctx = pagctx.getServletContext()
URL url = svltctx.getResource(virtualPath);
strFilePath = url.getFile();
File rscFile = new File(strFilePath);
```

**Output**:

file:/C:/_t/apptest/WEB-INF/lib/test1.jar!/META-INF/resources/js/script1.js

`rscFile.exists()` will return `false`
and
`rscFile.lastModified()` will return `0`
and because it returns `rscFile.exists() = false` maybe I should use: `File.getParent()`
and call it for every "path fragment" to get to the jar file and then open / unzip the jar file and get the packaged file "js/script1.js" and get the `File.lastModified()` ?